# Index Table with Geometry Column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table called `Stores` with 10k rows which has a column `location geometry(Point,4326)`.

```
CREATE INDEX "Stores_spatial_gix"
ON "Stores"
USING gist
(location);
```

Upon KNN query

```
explain analyze select *
 from "Stores"
 order by ST_distance_sphere(location,st_point(-82.373978, 29.633657)) limit 3
```

I get about 800ms each time. What am I doing wrong that it takes so long time?

Comment: Apparently ST_distance_sphere cant use indexes,http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53864/how-to-alter-this-postgis-st-distance-sphere-query-to-give-the-answer-for-all-po

Comment: So what is the right way to do KNN with a  `geometry` column? I don't have a specific range to use `ST_DWithin`

Comment: Sorry this is beyond my knowledge,try to post the question on gis.stack.

Comment: Question moved to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/154141/1872

Answer (score 0):

If you want KNN and have Postgres >=9.5 and postgis >=2.2 then use KNN operator

```
 SELECT *
   FROM "Stores"
  ORDER BY geom <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(-82.373978, 29.633657)'::geometry limit 3
```

Also if you use SRID=4326 then I would recommend geography, not geometry type>

If you can't use <->  operator due to an older version of PostGIS then I would recommend using st_dwithin with some medium value for distance like 1000 or 2000 meters(or something more accurate for your application). If you have to return always at least 3 points even if they are on the other part of the world then write a function with incremental changing of value for st_dwithin until it returns at least 3 rows.